# A question on finitely generated abelian groups

Tags: group-theory

Let $M$ be the torsion subgroup of a finitely generated abelian group $A$ with $M = 0$. Then it is not difficult to prove that there exists a $r \in \mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0}$ such that $A \cong Z^r$ . Furthermore, this $r$ is unique. Now, suppose that we are working with a finitely generated abelian group $B$, of which the torsion subgroup does not neccesarily need to be just $0$. How can we prove that $$B \cong N \times \mathbb{Z}^r$$

Where $N$ is the torsion subgroup of $B$. Surely the idea must be to consider the group $B/N$. Then $B/N \cong \mathbb{Z}^r$ for some $r \in \mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0}$. However, this doesn't directly imply that $B \cong N \times \mathbb{Z}^r$ or does it? How would I start solving this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pick representatives $e_1,\cdots,e_r$ of a set of generators of $B/N\cong\Bbb Z^r$, and prove that

$$B=N\times\langle e_1,\cdots,e_r\rangle$$

is an **internal direct product** with $\langle e_1,\cdots,e_r\rangle\cong B/N\cong\Bbb Z^r$.

(Note that the subgroup $N$ is uniquely determined by $B$, but $\langle e_1,\cdots,e_r\rangle$ isn't.)

Comment: Thanks so much for your response! I just had one more small question. In order to check that $B=N\times\langle e_1,\cdots,e_r\rangle$ we need to check that $N$ and $\langle e_1,\cdots,e_r\rangle$ are both normal subgroups of $B$ with trivial intersection such that every element in $B$ can be written as the product of an element in $N$ and an element in $\langle e_1,\cdots,e_r\rangle$. The first two claims are not difficult to prove but how do we prove the claim that every element in $B$ can be written as the product of an element in $N$ and an element in $\langle e_1,\cdots,e_r\rangle$?

Comment: @user119470 *General fact*: If $f:G\to H$ is a surjective group homomorphism with kernel $K$ and $M\le G$ is a subgroup such that $f(M)=H$, then $G=MK$. *Proof*: Let $g\in G$ be arbitrary. Let $m\in M$ be in the preimage of $f(g)$. Then $f(g)=f(m)$ so $g=m$ mod $K$ so $g=mk$ for some $k\in K$. *Application*: Here with $B\to B/N$ and $\langle e_1,\cdots,e_r\rangle\le B$.